# Buddypress - adding profile fields to Group > Members directory

Tags: buddypress

I'm trying to add custom profile fields to the member profiles that show on the Group > Single template but `bp_member_profile_data` doesn't seem to return anything.

This works fine when added to the members-loop.php:

```
<?php if ( bp_get_member_profile_data( 'field=Profile:' ) ) : ?>
  <?php echo '<BR><span class=memberslabel>Profile:</span> '; ?>
  <?php bp_member_profile_data( 'field=Profile:' ); ?>
<?php endif; ?>
```

But when I add it to `groups/single/members.php` it doesn't return anything.

Is there something special I need to add to make this function work in members.php?

**UPDATE**

The solution offered below works to get the profile data showing in on the group members loop, but it's showing the data of the last member for all members, I tried adding

`<?php $user_ID = get_current_user_id(); ?>`

and I also tried

`<?php echo xprofile_get_field_data( 'Profile:', $bp->displayed_user->id ); ?>`

but no change, how would I pass the relevant user ID into that function?

Also, it seems the profile fields are only showing for logged in users.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following function, which is the one i use:

```
 xprofile_get_field_data('Profile',$u_id);
```

**$u_id** is the user ID in case you are not in a members loop.

So in your case should be:

```
<?php if ( xprofile_get_field_data( 'Profile', $user_ID ) ) : ?>
  <?php echo '<BR><span class=memberslabel>Profile:</span> '; ?>
  <?php echo xprofile_get_field_data( 'Profile', $user_ID ); ?>
<?php endif; ?>
```

UPDATE : You will need to paste your whole code to be sure you are using this on the right place. But you could try something like:

```
<?php while ( bp_group_members() ) : bp_group_the_member(); ?>

            <li>
                <a href="<?php bp_group_member_domain(); ?>">

                    <?php bp_group_member_avatar_thumb(); ?>

                </a>

                <h5><?php bp_group_member_link(); ?></h5>
                <span class="activity"><?php bp_group_member_joined_since(); ?></span>

                <?php do_action( 'bp_group_members_list_item' ); ?>

                <?php if ( bp_is_active( 'friends' ) ) : ?>

                    <div class="action">

                        <?php bp_add_friend_button( bp_get_group_member_id(), bp_get_group_member_is_friend() ); ?>

                        <?php do_action( 'bp_group_members_list_item_action' ); ?>

                    </div>

                <?php endif; ?>
                <?php 
                          $user_ID = bp_get_group_member_id();
                          if ( xprofile_get_field_data( 'Profile', $user_ID ) ) : ?>
                          <?php echo '<BR><span class=memberslabel>Profile:</span> '; ?>
                               <?php echo xprofile_get_field_data( 'Profile', $user_ID ); ?>
                <?php endif; ?>
            </li>

        <?php endwhile; ?>
```

Comment: Actually not quite perfectly, see my edit above.

Comment: i updated my question with bp_get_group_member_id()

Comment: Thanks very much chifliiiii I haven't had a chance to get back to this yet but I'll take a closer tomorrow and let you know how it works, and paste in my code if necessary.

Comment: You rock so much, thanks - it now really is working perfectly! Cheers!